# How to make single point crossover between two matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I need to do crossover by taking any two matrices using single point cross over. What is the code for that in Matlab?

```
n=input('no.of ROWS AND COLUMNS');
sm_mat = eye(n);
for i=1:n
    temp = randperm(n);
    fprintf('Initial Population %d\n',i)
    eval(['sm_mat_', num2str(i) '=sm_mat(:,temp)']);
end
```

Comment: I need to take any two matrix and want to cross over .. the above creates 1's in different place with each row one 1's.

Comment: Any additional info for the question, like the code you posted, should be added to the question itself. You can use the [edit] link right below your question's tab (or the two [edit] links in my comment).

Comment: Please edit your question by using proper code formatting (i.e. the curly brackets). Also, clarify (with an example would be lovely) along which dimension the crossover should be performed.

Comment: Where are the matrices to crossover? You have only 1.

Comment: Using for loop I have created n matrices from that I want to pick any two and want to process it.

Comment: By Taking any row and want to crossover that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what your problem is, you can easily do manually the One-Point Crossover. So you do want to create `n` possible parents, randomly select two of them and then performing the crossover between their rows in order to create a new individual (child).

Instead of creating different variables for each (candidate) parent (this will make the random selection of such two parents incredibly hard) I suggest you to create a cell array with `n` cells where the i-th cell will contain the i-th matrix (candidate parent).

```
n=input('no.of ROWS AND COLUMNS');
sm_mat = eye(n);
for i=1:n
    temp = randperm(n);
%     fprintf('Initial Population %d\n',i)
%     eval(['sm_mat_', num2str(i) '=sm_mat(:,temp)']);
    InitialPopCell{i}=sm_mat(:,temp);
end
```

`InitialPopCell` will be our cell array.
Now you need to randomly select two parents: to do so, you can simply select two different cells randomly.

```
i=0; j=0;
while i==j
    i=randi(n);
    j=randi(n);
end
```

In this manner we select two indices (`i` and `j`) taking into account that they must be in range [1:n] and they must be different from each other.
Now we can select the two parents:

```
ParentA=InitialPopCell{i};
ParentB=InitialPopCell{j};
Child=[];
```

and we also initialized as empty the `Child` (i.e. new individual) matrix.
Now, finally, let's perform the crossover:

```
for i=1:size(ParentA,1)
    % select random integer between 1 and the number of chromosomes
    % this will be the crossover point
    XOverPoint=randi(size(ParentA,2));

    % create new individual by concatenating Parent A and B taking into
    % account the crossover point
    Child(i,:)=[ParentA(i,1:XOverPoint) ParentB(i,XOverPoint+1:end)];
end
```